# Hibernate query - username like with multiple inputs

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i am tried to get user by criteria, but getting error like below

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: '{test%,testuser6,%ana%}' near line 1, column 108 [

SELECT jpauser FROM com.abc.domain.jpa.JpaUser jpauser WHERE  jpauser.username like  ANY('{test%,testuser6,%ana%}'::text[]) limit 100]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
```

Code:

```
public List<JpaUser> getUserByCriteria(String criteria)
    {
        Query query = getEntityManager()
                .createQuery("SELECT jpauser FROM JpaUser jpauser WHERE " + criteria);
        List<JpaUser> result = query.getResultList();
        return result;
    }
```

I just copied and executed the query in PostgreSQL terminal, its works fine, but through hibernate query its failed

Here is the query i have executed in PostgreSQL

```
SELECT * FROM users jpauser WHERE  jpauser.username like  ANY('{test%,testuser6,%ana%}'::text[]) limit 100
```

Construct the criteria like below

```
String value = criteria.get("username");
                builder.append(TABLE_ALIAS).append("username").append(" like ")
                .append(ANY).append("('{").append(value).append("}'::text[])")
```

Can any one help on this, how to execute hibernate query with like and multiple input ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `createNativeQuery` for native query

```
Query query = getEntityManager()
                .createNativeQuery("SELECT jpauser FROM JpaUser jpauser WHERE " + criteria);
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, but getting below error after i changed to 'createNativeQuery'              
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement
 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
 at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
 at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)

Comment: Can you add your full stack trace in question, seems your SQL syntax is wrong check again, and share also how you prepare `criteria`

Comment: added above how i prepare criteria..... getting error like below......
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "ANY" not found; SQL statement:
SELECT jpauser FROM users jpauser WHERE  jpauser.username like  ANY('{test%,testuser6,%ana%}':text[]) limit 100 [90022-191]
 at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)

Comment: Jdbc don't find your `PSQL Function` add your properties file are you use correct config and add your config in your question

Comment: And check also PSQL dialect which are you using support your db current version

Answer (score 0):

In a native query, You need to use native SQL statment:

```
Query query = getEntityManager()
            .createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM users jpauser WHERE " + criteria)
```

Comment: getting error like below...... Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Function "ANY" not found; SQL statement: SELECT * FROM users jpauser WHERE jpauser.username like ANY('{test%,testuser6,%ana%}':text[]) limit 100 [90022-191] at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)

Comment: The reason is `org.h2`. It is wrong DB. I assume You want to run this query on PostgresSQL.